# Listview Item onclick a label to show textwrap only on the selected listitem

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

In listview items I have a label. when click on the label it has to expand the text.**For eg:** By default it will show only one line of label text.When I click on that label text, it has to expand 10 lines of label(That means label content description has 10 lines).

**What is happening:**

When click on the first listview item label, it is expanding the label to 10 lines perfectly using textWrap. But it is automatically expanding the fourth list item label also.

**What I need:**

When clicking on the first listview item label, it should only expand the first listview item textWrap. Not the fourth list item label text.

Below I have posted the relevant code:

**ts file:**

```
onClickList(args: EventData, index: number): void {

  let labelArg = <Label>args.object;

  var listview: ListView = <ListView>this.page.getViewById("listviewId");

  listview.refresh();

  labelArg.textWrap = true;

  listview.refresh();  

}
```

**html file:**

```
<ListView id="listviewId" [items]="_myFeedsList" class="list-group">
  <ng-template let-item="item" let-i="index">
    <StackLayout id="stackId">
      ....... .......
      <Label textWrap="false" id="labelID" [text]="item.data" (tap)="onClickList($event, i)"></Label>

    </StackLayout </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something very simple if you just want to toggle textWrap value of tapped item  :

**ts file :**

```
toggle(event) {
    if (event.object.textWrap) {
      event.object.textWrap = false;
    } else {
      event.object.textWrap = true;
    }
}
```

**html file, replace  line with following :**

```
<Label [textWrap]="false" [id]="'label' + i" [text]="item.data" (tap)="toggle($event)"></Label>
```

You can see that I changed the `Label` id to a dynamic value so you can select each of them later if you want. That's not what makes this work but it's much cleaner than giving same id to every of them.

Working example here : https://github.com/mickaeleuranie/nativescript-stackoverflow-46910984

Comment: thanks.this answer is working good as i'm expected.but the only issue is, i have seen  when click on the 5th listview item label, it is expanding that text. But what happens when scrolling up and coming back again , 6th listitem label is automatically wrapping(expanding) up and 5th remains hided.

Answer (score 0):

I am not nativeScript 'expert', so I will try to explain the principe only.  Keep a property/field for the clicked label. For the start/default value give it -1. Each time a label is clicked, set the property value to label's index value (i in your code). And show/hide/expand lines of the label based on the condition if the label has that property value. Hope it's clear enough.

```
selected = -1;

<Label textWrap="false" id="labelID" [text]="item.data" (tap)="selected = i; onClickList($event, i)"></Label>
```

Comment: is tap or itemTap?